# Output some development metric for each muscle of the human body given a picture of a human

Tags: computer-vision

I am looking for a program or web service that takes as input a picture of a human, and outputs some development metric for each muscle of the human body. By development metric, I mean some metric that quantifies how developed/large a muscle is.

Any price, license or operating system is fine.